# how do I unit test this function which handles observables

Tags: rxjs, angular6, angular-test

I have created this function because for all the requests my application sends out using `http.post`, this is how different parts handle the response. So rather than duplicating the code, I thought to create a function. But I am unable to figure out how to unit test this function.

```
private editAnswerSubject: Subject<Result>;
subscribeToReturnedObservable(observable:Observable<any>, subject:Subject<Result>) {
    observable.subscribe((res) => {
        const ev = <HttpEvent<any>>(res);
        if (ev.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          const isResponseStructureOK: boolean = this.helper.validateServerResponseStructure(ev.body);
          if (isResponseStructureOK) {
            const response: ServerResponseAPI = ev.body;
            subject.next(new Result(response.result, response['additional-info']));

          } else {
            subject.next(new Result(messages.error, messages.invalidStructureOfResponse));
          }
        }
      },
      (error: ServerResponseAPI) => {
        const errorMessage: string = this.helper.userFriendlyErrorMessage(error);
        subject.next(new Result(messages.error, errorMessage));    
      },
      () => { // observable complete
      });
  }

  editAnswer(answer: Answer): any {
    const observable = this.bs.editAnswer(answer)
    this.subscribeToReturnedObservable(observable,this.editAnswerSubject);
  }
```

The test I have written so far is

```
  describe('subscribeToReturnedObservable tests:', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [QuestionManagementService, HelperService, WebToBackendInterfaceService, AuthService, HttpClient, HttpHandler]
      });
    });

fit('should call send next value for the subject is the response from the server is ok', () => {
  const questionService:QuestionManagementService = TestBed.get(QuestionManagementService);
  const body = {"result":"success", "additional-info":"some additional info"};
  const receivedHttpEvent = new HttpResponse({body:body});
  let observable = new Observable();
  spyOn(observable,'subscribe').and.returnValue(receivedHttpEvent);
  spyOn(questionService['editQuestionSubject'],'next');
  questionService.subscribeToReturnedObservable(observable,questionService['editQuestionSubject']);
  observable.subscribe();
  expect(questionService['editQuestionSubject'].next).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

But it get error `Expected spy next to have been called.`

Comment: `spyOn(observable,'subscribe').and.returnValue(receivedHttpEvent);` won't work because `subscribe` returns Subscription and `receivedHttpEvent` should be emitted by `observable`.

Comment: thanks martin. I guess my doubt is how do I make `observable.subscribe((res)=>...` run with `receivedHttpEvent.`. I am not able to figure that out.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md or if you can make a stackblitz demo I can have a look

Comment: Thanks martin. I have tried an alternative way. Thanks for introduce me to Marbel testing. I didn't know about it. I also found this article useful - https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-test-observables-a00038c7faad

Comment: Martin =-I thought to try using marbel testing to simulate error scenario but I am stuck. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337404/unable-to-write-a-test-case-with-marbel-testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this (hoping that it is the right way). The scope of testing is to check that the `Subject`'s  `next` is called correctly. So create an `Observable` using `of` and let the code flow from there.

```
fit('should call send next value for the subject is the response from the server is ok', () => {
  const questionService:QuestionManagementService = TestBed.get(QuestionManagementService);
  const helperService:HelperService = TestBed.get(HelperService);
  const body = {"result":"success", "additional-info":"some additional info"};
  const receivedHttpEvent = new HttpResponse({body:body});
  const expectedResult = new Result('success', 'some additional info');
  spyOn(helperService,'validateServerResponseStructure').and.returnValue(true);
  let observable = of(receivedHttpEvent);
  spyOn(questionService['editQuestionSubject'],'next');
  questionService.subscribeToReturnedObservable(observable,questionService['editQuestionSubject']);
  expect(questionService['editQuestionSubject'].next).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedResult);
});
```